# Convert mnemonic MARC to regular MARC

Tags: java, spring-boot, marc

Using a Java Spring-boot application I am reading from a server Marc21 records in mnemonic Marc. 
ie

```
000 00000nam  22000007a 0000
001 14714137
003 LIBRIS
007 cr||||||||||||
008 130925  |||||||sw      ||||||||||1|swe
020 __ $a9789127137004
```

To be able to handle this information and save it I would prefer if the information was given with ISO standard ISO-2709, so I could use Marc4j.

Does anyone in this community know how I could programmatically convert the files on the fly? Is it even possible? If it is, it would be appreciated if you could include a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Yaz tool calls "line" format. You could use yaz-marcdump to do this conversion I believe.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/yaz-marcdump

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using marcedit?

Comment: No! I would like to solve this issue programmatically and not manually. There are millions of records. Also I'm not sure MarcEdit can open mnemonic MARC.

Comment: MarcEdit can definitely open mnemonic MARC